# Fill a DataGrid with LINQ expression

Tags: c#

I can't fill a datagrid with this code:

```cs
var y = valores.Where(c => c % 2 == 0);                 
dataGridView1.DataSource = y.ToList();
```

But this works:

```cs
var x = from valor in valores
        where (valor % 2 == 0)
        select new
        {
            valor
        };

dataGridView1.DataSource = x.ToList();
```

Comment: Your second one is using an anonymous type, for no particularly obvious reason. But when you say you "can't" fill a datagrid, please could you clarify what you mean? What happens when you *try* to use the code in the first snippet?

Comment: The second one has a select.

Comment: The first is a list of `valor` objects, the 2nd one is list of `{ Valor valor; }` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may see from the result of your queries:

[image]

you are getting two different lists. The first one returns the integers value type, the second one is returning valor which is anonymous type list.

[image]

In order to fix the first query you should edit your code from:

`var y = valores.Where(c => c % 2 == 0);`

to

`var y = valores.Where(c => c % 2 == 0).Select(c => new { valor = c });`

Comment: I want to tanks to every all, special to Miodrag that clarify this thing for me.

Comment: @PauloPraca you are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if you believe that is the best solution to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

> I can't fill a datagrid

Apparently you mean that your `dataGridView1` is not displaying the list.

I reproduced your problem and did an experiment with some types. Looks like the reason is when the list contains objects which has **no properties** then `DataGridView` does not get bound to the list. In your first snippet, for example, the Linq expression is returning a list of integers, which is `System.Int32`. And if you take a look at the definition of this value type with object browser then you can see that it **does not declare any public property**.

For example following code "does not work" either

```
var x = from valor in valores
where (valor % 2 == 0)
select new
{    
};
dataGridView1.DataSource = x.ToList();
```

That is, I am creating object of anonymous type with **no properties**.

Like `System.Int32` a list of `System.Double` or `System.Decimal` "does not work" either.

Unlike `System.Int32` a list of `System.DateTime`s works because `DateTime` has properties.

So my conclusion is if a type does not contain any property then a list of instances of this type will not be bound to the `DataGridView`.